error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'. How can I fix it?
I use Jupyter notebook with Python 3.12.3 on a windows 11. I installed PyPDF2 to use it with streamlit. But I get the error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'.
How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.
I try read a pdf file with PyPDF2
import PyPDF2

Following on what KJ said, you aren't using up to the date information. Here, where the Python Packing Index page for PyPDF2 referred you for current versions,  it clearly states for import statement to use from pypdf import PdfReader. (Not the import statement you are trying according to your post.) If you are using steamlit in the same environment as you are using Jupyter, you can do %pip install pypdf in a running Jupyter .ipynb file to install to the environment where that kernel will be running.

 If you still get a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to use pypdf in streamlit, run in the place you are using to invoke streamlit which python and then try to see if your earlier install went to that same environment or elsewhere. Just because you installed something somewhere on your machine, doesn't mean software that needs it will know where it is. Alternatively, if you can successfully run %pip install pypdf in Jupyter and the import statement does indeed work when you try it, you may be able to run !streamlit run ... (... = rest of command) in a cell in your notebook.
